# How do I use selenium in Python to select a calendar date when Python won't let me click on anything because I can't click on lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I'm trying to click on the calendar in this website so I can choose a date to see the weather on that date:

[Link](https://www.worldweatheronline.com/kaohsiung-weather-history/tai-wan/tw.aspx)

The first step would be to click on the calendar icon so the calendar shows up so I can click on a date. When I right-click on the icon and inspect it, this is the code:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContentHolder$txtPastDate" type="date" value="2022-01-07" id="ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate" class="form-control">
```

I try to do it in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from pandas.io.html import read_html
driver=wd.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.worldweatheronline.com/kaohsiung-weather-history/tai-wan/tw.aspx')
f=get_html(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_elements_by_id('ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate').click()
```

All I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-113-f6eee7773e00>", line 5, in <module>
    driver.find_elements_by_id('ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate').click()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

I can't seem to click anything because whenever I extract something, Python saves that thing as a list, and lists don't click.

I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Spyder 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)                                 
driver.get('https://www.worldweatheronline.com/kaohsiung-weather-history/tai-wan/tw.aspx')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='AGREE']"))).click()
element=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate")))
value='2020-01-01'
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value',arguments[1])",element, value)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.introjs-skipbutton"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#ctl00_MainContentHolder_butShowPastWeather"))).click()
```

In order to set that value you can use javascript to set but first remove the agree button, change units and then click the show past weather afterwards.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `find_elements` return a list of web element, not a single web element.

Also, on a python `list` we can not invoke `.click` method. that explain the error that you've got.

So instead of

```
driver.find_elements_by_id('ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate').click()
```

use this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_MainContentHolder_txtPastDate').click()
```

Comment: thanks! important to know for the future.

Comment: The convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can send keys too if you'd like to, with a desired date. Not every website facilitates with this feature (and this website has), but when it is there, you may use it.
You may use the below locator strategy.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='date']").send_keys("05-01-2022")
```

Of course, do not hard-code the date into the code. Keep it in a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried this with a slight tweak and it worked.